# Read/Write metrics from Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to get detail Datastore metrics? I am interested in reads and writes a sort of historical data. I would like visually to see whenever changes in the stack happens how Datastore utilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of metrics provided for Datastore in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-datastore):

- api/request_count
- entity/read_sizes
- entity/write_sizes
- index/write_count

A straight forward way to observer them is to use Stackdriver Monitoring > Resources > Metrics Explorer > Find resource type and metric.

Comment: Thanks so much! I missed that when I was looking for in Stackdriver.  Also, I was wondering if I could get a count on reads/writes/deletes so I can kind of see loads and sort of match to pricing - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing